# How to change Tomcat classpath

Tags: java, tomcat, classpath

I have I have standart servlet webapp using Spring WebApplicatonContext defined in web.xml
. Web.xml path is `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml`. App works on Tomcat 7 server.

I'm trying to get this web.xml file for parsing in DAO class: `File webXMLFile = new File("web.xml");`

When i'm trying to deploy app in Tomcat 7 i get following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\hedw1q\.SmartTomcat\UCS-test-project\UCS-test-project\web.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:70)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:161)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:652)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:186)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:772)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:232)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:208)
at ru.hedw1q.dao.DAOImpl.getQueryByName(DAOImpl.java from InputFileObject:62)
at ru.hedw1q.dao.DAOImpl.getJSONEntry(DAOImpl.java from InputFileObject:47)
at ru.hedw1q.controller.DefaultController.getJSONRow(DefaultController.java from InputFileObject:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1201)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:654)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:317)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Why tomcat is searching file in /.SmartTomcat folder? How to change classpath to application folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing a local file, not a classpath resource, therefore the classpath has nothing to do with the error.

`web.xml` is a relative file path and Tomcat deals with relative paths like every other application: it resolves it against the current working directory. The current working directory can be anything, e.g. Eclipse by default launches Tomcat in its own working directory. You should (almost) **never** use a relative file path in a servlet.

If you want to retrieve a resource relative to the application root you should use [`ServletContext#getResource`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource-java.lang.String-), its Spring abstraction [`ResourceLoader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) or use the `@Resource` annotation (cf. [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-annotations-resource-inject-autowire)).